# KDB/Q: How to fetch record with timestamp just before a given timestamp

Tags: database, kdb

I need to fetch a single record with a given sym that has the latest time value *just before* a given time. This is what I tried to do:

```
tableName asof `sym`time!(`12345;20:05:27.000)
```

But I get the following error:

```
The server sent the response:
splay
Studio Hint: Possibly this refers to nyi op on splayed table
```

Earlier, I tried the following (which worked):

```
select last time from tableName where
    sym = `12345,
    time < 20:05:27.000
```

But per my understanding, this sort of query will have a much worse performance than a query that makes use of `asof`. Can `asof` not be used on splayed tables?  Is there a workaround for this? What would be the best way to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following select statement in order to map your table from disk into memory should work:

```
(select from tableName) asof `sym`time!(`12345;20:05:27.000)
```

Comment: Is it okay to do this even if the table is really large?

Comment: When I tried this on a dummy splayed trades table, the memory footprint was low as it's mapping as opposed to copying the table into memory (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/aj/). I should note your initial query also has a relatively low memory footprint as its not copying much data into memory.
`q)\ts:100 select last time from trades where sym=`AAPL, time < 20:05:27.000
29 3984
q)\ts:100 (select from trades) asof `sym`time!(`AAPL;20:05:27.000)
72 2256`
Although if you're working with a partitioned database (e.g. partitioned by date) you'll perhaps need a where clause to maintain mapping.

Comment: I think it would be very important to have a `p# attribute on the sym column if the table is large. That should ensure the asof is optimal